# Can you ask a moderator to delete one of your questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, moderators

Can you ask a moderator to delete one of your questions that has an answer?

I have many questions posted a while back which were not asked very nicely and produced no real answers to help other users. These questions were asked when I first started on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can _ask_, but if it has an answer, why should it be deleted? It still provides value to the community.

Comment: The question i'm talking about i think would be more of a distraction to someone looking for answers, there are many similar questions ask in a better way with better answers.

Comment: You can delete it yourself as long as it doesn't have upvoted answers, there's "delete" link next to "edit" below the question body.

Comment: @Pomster If it's asking the same thing as another (better) question with better answers, then you might want to consider having it closed as a duplicate of one of those rather than deleting it entirely. That way if somebody comes across your question it can act as a sign post to those other questions/answers.

Comment: Ok so do i flag a request to close it? How do i close a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can flag your question with a custom ("other") flag, explaining what it is you want and why.

But there is no guarantee whatsoever that they will do so. Especially if that would mean removing valuable content in the form of answers.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i understand keeping a bad question containing a valuable answer but the questions and answers i'm talking about have no valuable information to provide the community with. Thanks

Comment: Yet the answer must have received upvotes, thereby indicating some value. But in any case, you can try, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: If someone can clearly learn something as a result of reading the question and the answers it received, it's probably worth keeping. That said, if something compels you to believe it's actively _harmful_ for some reason, and you can't just fix it - make sure you explain it clearly in your flag.